# Unable to store the edited contents to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I inserted some values using a form,and the values stored in  database successfully. And I echo the stored values to the table using the HTML coding using while loop.And I made all the td(table content) editable,which can be edited. Since I am new to programming, struggling to store the edited values to database, can anybody help with any query,concept ??

My Code

```
<?php
     if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            $qry="DELETE FROM nifty WHERE id =" .$_GET['id'];
            mysql_query($qry);
        }
     if(isset($_GET['rid']))
        {
        $qry1="UPDATE nifty WHERE id =" .$_GET['rid'];
        mysql_query($qry1);
        echo $qry1;
     }
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nifty");

        echo "<table  class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>B/S</th>
    <th>Entry Point</th>
    <th>Exit Point</th>
    <th>P/L</th>
    <th style='width:50px;'>Action</th>
    </tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr>";?>
      <td contenteditable="true">
                    <?php echo $row['date']; ?>
                </td>

      <td contenteditable="true">
                    <?php echo $row['bs']; ?>
                </td>


     <td contenteditable="true">
                    <?php echo $row['entrypoint']; ?>
                </td>

     <td contenteditable="true">
                    <?php echo $row['exitpoint']; ?>
                </td>
     <td contenteditable="true">
                    <?php echo $row['pl']; ?>
                </td>
     <td width=10%>
             <?php echo "<a href='?rid=".$row['id']."' title='Sure You want to save this Record;' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure to save this Record?');\"><img src='images/edit.png'></a>"; ?>&nbsp&nbsp<?php echo "<a href='?id=".$row['id']."' title='You want to cancel this booking;' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?');\"><img src='images/delete.png'></a>"; ?></td>
    <?php
      echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";?>
```

Comment: Hi @sheik, can you explain me in detail about your question?

Comment: I don't see any form inputs here.  You'll need to create a form which posts the fields you want updated to your script.  Then run an `UPDATE` query to save them like `UPDATE nifty SET field = 'value' WHERE id = id;`...

Comment: the echoed database contents should be available to be edited and updated in the database @ Karthik N

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is given to update values in the UPDATE query. Provide them, then you can save the edited data in database.
Change From 
$qry1="UPDATE nifty WHERE id =" .$_GET['rid'];

To 
$qry1="UPDATE nifty SET fieldname = 'fieldvalue' WHERE id =" .$_GET['rid'];

Comment: can u please give me the update query to update the coloumn(date) of my table

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry1="UPDATE nifty SET date = '".$required_date."' WHERE id =" .$_GET['rid'];
```

Where :

$required_date = date stored in a variable that you want to update